# Online meeting scheduling time allowing different timeslots per day

Tags: web-apps, scheduling

I want to schedule a meeting, similar to how [whenisgood](http://whenisgood.net/) and [doodle](http://doodle.com/) work.

However, my use case is that I want to only present options outside the normal 9-5 workday. Such as:

- Saturday morning
- Saturday afternoon
- Saturday evening
- Sunday morning
- Sunday afternoon
- Sunday evening
- Monday evening
- Tuesday evening

etc.

Anyways, I found that both doodle/whenisgood do not work for this - they seem to only take a set schedule and apply it to all days in the range (ie if I selected May 12 through June 12, the times are identical per day).

Is there an online scheduling tool similar to this?

Answer (score 2):

We use [Calendly](https://calendly.com) for scheduling appointments and setting meeting times.

You can set blocks of time to when you are only available. These are the only times they can set appointments with you. Best thing is it automatically adjusts the scheduler's time based on his timezone.